# Selenium Issues With Waiting Until Multiple Dropdowns Populate

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am having a great amount of trouble working with python selenium on a multi-dropdown url retrieval algorithm. In short, I'd like my program to go the the link (https://www.xpel.com/clearbra-installers/) and iterate through each of the three location dropdowns to retrieve every possible final link (i.e. https://www.xpel.com/clearbra-installers/united-states/california/bakersfield).

I have tried several different methods of doing this, including clicking on the table options, iterating through the dropdowns, and even collecting dataframes of each dropdown option, then creating urls and going to those links. However I try to approach the problem, there I always hit a snag related to wait times and "stale element not found" errors.

Here is the html I'm trying to scrape:

```
<select class="dealer-locator-select" id="dealer-locator-country-select" name="dealer-locator-country-select" data-action="country-select" data-filter="">
<option value=""> Region, Country or Area </option>
<option value="albania"> Albania </option>
<option value="algeria"> Algeria </option>
<option value="argentina"> Argentina </option>
<option value="armenia"> Armenia </option>
<option value="australia"> Australia </option>
<option value="austria"> Austria </option>
<option value="bahrain"> Bahrain </option>
<option value="belgium"> Belgium </option>
<option value="bosnia-and-herzegovina"> Bosnia and Herzegovina </option>
...
<option value="vietnam"> Vietnam </option>
</select>
```

Here is some code I've tried for retrieving countries:

```
# set wait
delay = 10 # seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay)

# iterate through country options
for i in range(2,96):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]")))
    country_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]").text.lower().replace(' ', '-')
    country = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']")).select_by_value(country_name)

print("done")
```

The code seems to work find until the selection; for instance, if I just retrieve the country name then print it, everything works perfectly. I've also tried using try/except/finally, which I haven't had luck with either:

```
# set wait
delay = 10 # seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay)

# iterate through each country option
for i in range(2,96):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]")))
    country_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]").text.lower().replace(' ', '-')
    try:
        country = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']"))
    except:
        sleep(5)
        country = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']"))
    finally:
        country.select_by_value(country_name)

print("done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `StaleElementReferenceException` as far as dropdown is re-rendered after new options selection.

As far as you don't wait for re-rendering, your script on next iteration gets old reference that doesn't exist anymore and can't be reached.

To handle this case, should wait for old dropdown element to be stale after selection.

```py
for i in range(2,96):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]")))
    country_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]").text.lower().replace(' ', '-')
    country_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']")
    country = Select(country_element)
    country.select_by_value(country_name)
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(country_element))
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! This solution saved my life. Also I'm just curious, what does 'staleness' of an element entail? Does this just mean that the new page has loaded so 'country_element' is not accessible any more?

Comment: Some elements have custom render logic, so after some actions like input / selection it's content can be re-rendered. It's usually made to not to increase DOM elements amount on each action. For example, triggering first dropdown needs 2nd and 3rd dropdown content to be consistent. So, I guess, devs decided to re-render that components block after select action.

Answer (score 0):

The idea in the link you shared is that a new page is being rendered based on every dropdown choice. For example, selecting Algeria from the first dropdown forces the browser to open https://www.xpel.com/clearbra-installers/algeria. If the user then selects blida state then a new page is rendered https://www.xpel.com/clearbra-installers/algeria/blida and so on.
So you have to reselect all dropdowns again with any action you are doing.

The solution in my point of view to add a delay (5 seconds as an example) after each country.select_by_value statement then reselect the dropdowns again because the page content has been changed.

Also it might be a good idea to add a delay at the end of your loop just to make sure the dynamic content is loaded.

Example:

```
# set wait
delay = 10 # seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay)

# iterate through country options
for i in range(2,96):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]")))
    country_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']/option[" + str(i) + "]").text.lower().replace(' ', '-')
    country_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='dealer-locator-country-select']")
    country = Select(country_element)
    country.select_by_value(country_name)
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(country_element))


print("done")
```